# css grid layout - height of rows never works

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to use percentages in my css for my react app but it's causing such a headache. Width % work fantastic all the time but the height % is always an issue. It seems almost like I HAVE to specify a height in pixels for it to work work unless the element contains children.

Am I missing something fundamental here. Will a div not set itself to 100% of the remaining height without child elements. The below code doesn't work despite me setting the align-items property to stretch.

```css
.search-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 900px 300px auto;
    grid-template-rows: 30% auto auto;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.promo-container {
    background-color:blue;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.form-container {
    background-color:blue;
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.results-header {
    background-color:rgb(255, 94, 0);
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    height: 90px;
}

.refine-search {
    background-color:blue;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    height: 100%;
}

.results-container{
    background-color:rgb(0, 255, 42);
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
}
```

```html
<div className="search-container">
  <div className="promo-container">
  </div>              
  <div className="form-container">
  </div>
  <div className="results-header">
  </div>
  <div className="refine-search">
  </div>
  <div className="results-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 30% of which parent reference ? if none then 30% equals null . set an height on direct parent or use a unit as vh , px or else that do not require to be calculated on parent's height set in CSS

Comment: I think this is where I'm going completely wrong, I'm so used to using flex in react native that I'm not doing precisely whaty you've just said. So I'm assuming that I would need to set my root element at 100vh for this to work?

Comment: or use 30vh as value for the first row ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the height of your parent elements.

```
html, body, div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with height is that you need to have some childrens in order to work. So if you want to see the blank space where is supposed to be the childrens ( the rest of the elements) you indeed have to set pixels, rem, fr, etc. Otherwise The grid won't allow the blank space to be there if there's nothing in there. For example if I want to see my remaining space I can say:

```
`.someClass {
   display: grid; 
   /* I'm setting the rows to be 3 row with a given space of 1 fr 
    each row will be placed with given space unit */
   grid-templates-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
   grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}`
```

Otherwise if you want to create the grid depending automatically on the availaible space you can set everything to auto like so:

```
.someotherClass {
 display: grid;
 /* grid template areas is the combination of the template rows and columns */
 grid-templates-areas: auto;
 }
```

Of course with the `auto` I can still order my items on the rows and columns that I want but the space will be adjusted accordingly with each element

To give you some idea how the grid works check out this page: https://cssgridgarden.com/

Hope helps :)